# How to correctly configure path in this structure for gulp

Tags: javascript, angularjs, path, gulp

I have this question on how to properly configure the path on this folder structure.. So my folder structure is:

```
bower_components/
node_modules/
app/
   components/
              home/
                   controller/
                              homeCtrl.js
                   css/
                         home.css
                   home.html

    shared/
           css/
           directives/
           filters/
           directives/
           sass/
           services/
assets/
    audio/
    debug/
    lib/
    etc...

gulp/
   paths.js

gulpfile.js
index.html
etc....
```

As shown above you can see the folder structure, if you want to work this with me you can go [here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm), and we can solve the problem quick and fast! Otherwise, above is an example of my structure.. And in my paths.js i have:

```
module.exports = {
    dest: 'assets/dist',
    js: [
        'app/app.module.js',
        'app/app.run.js',
        'app/shared/**/*.module.js',
        'app/shared/**/*.js',
        'app/components/**/*.js',
        'app/components/**/*.module.js'
    ],
    sass: ['app/shared/**/*.sass'],
    vendor_js: [
         'bower_components/angular/angular.js',
         'bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.js',
         'bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
         'bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.min.js',
         'bower_components/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js',
         'bower_components/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js',
         'bower_components/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js',
         'bower_components/firebase/firebase.min.js',
         'bower_components/angularfire/dist/angularfire.min.js',
         'assets/lib/svg-assets-cache/svg-assets-cache.js',
         'node_modules/alertifyjs/build/alertify.min.js',
         'bower_components/vex/js/vex.combined.min.js',
         'bower_components/clipboard/dist/clipboard.min.js',
         'bower_components/marked/lib/marked.js',
         'bower_components/highlightjs/highlight.pack.js',
         'bower_components/angular-socialshare/dist/angular-socialshare.min.js',
         'assets/lib/Recaptcha/googleRecaptchaAPI.js',
         'bower_components/angular-recaptcha/release/angular-recaptcha.min.js',
         'assets/lib/angular-screenfull/angular-screenfull.min.js',
         'assets/lib/screenfull/screenfull.min.js',
         'bower_components/selectize/dist/js/standalone/selectize.min.js',
         'assets/lib/angular-selectize/angular-selectize.js'
    ],
    vendor_styles: [
        'bower_components/selectize/dist/css/selectize.css',
        'bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css',
        'node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css',
        'node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/semantic.min.css',
        'bower_components/vex/css/vex.css',
        'bower_components/vex/css/vex-theme-flat-attack.css',
        'assets/lib/material-charts/material-charts.min.css'
    ]
};
```

And in gulpfile.js:

```
//Require Gulp
var gulp = require("gulp");
var ngAnnotate = require("gulp-ng-annotate");
var uglify = require("gulp-uglify");
var concat = require("gulp-concat");
var sourceMaps = require("gulp-sourcemaps");
var util = require('gulp-util');
var clean = require("gulp-clean");
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
// var minifyCss = require('gulp-minify-css');

var paths = require("./gulp/paths");

//remove temporary directories like dist
gulp.task('clean', function() {
    return gulp.src('assets/dist', {read: false})
    .pipe(clean());
});

// combines all js files into one and create sourcemaps for them
gulp.task('scripts', function(done) {
    gulp.src(paths.js)
    .pipe(sourceMaps.init())
    .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
    .pipe(ngAnnotate())
    .pipe(uglify().on('error', util.log))
    .pipe(sourceMaps.write('.'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest))
    .on('error', util.log)
    .on('end', done);
});

gulp.task('watch', function() {
    gulp.watch(paths.js, ['scripts'])
});

gulp.task('scripts:vendor', function() {
   return gulp.src(paths.vendor_js)
    .pipe(concat('vendor.min.js'))
    // .pipe(uglify().on('error', util.log))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    console.log("running gulp");
});
```

When i run it, it tells me Angular is undefined.. I am very sure this is because of the path, because when I change path it doesn't give me the error, but still says 'Angular is not defined'. Help would be greatly appreciated, we can solve it [here](https://ide.c9.io/amanuel2/ng-fourm) too...

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" class="html_container">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!--<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1200">
    <title>Ng-Forum</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/alertify.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/alertifyjs/build/css/themes/semantic.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/vex/css/vex.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/vex/css/vex-theme-flat-attack.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/amanuel2/MathGame/master/chartjs/material-charts.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/angular-material/angular-material.css" />
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>

<body ng-app="ForumApp">
    <div ui-view></div>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.9/angular.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javscript" src="assets/dist/vendor.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="assets/dist/app.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: In your `index.html`, are you including the vendor scripts before the app scripts? Also, if you are planning to use the full jQuery with Angular, instead of Angular's jqlite, place it before Angular in the `vendor_js` array.

Comment: Let me post the index.html @NikosParaskevopoulos

Comment: You are including Angular twice: in the `code.angularjs.org` and in `vendor.min.js`; try removing one.

Comment: i already tried that @NikosParaskevopoulos